# Alternatives to logistic regression if there are zero counts

Tags: regression, logistic, contingency-tables, fishers-exact-test

I have three variables (let's call them $A$, class (both binary) and age (numerical)), and I want to test if there is a difference in the presence of A between the two classes, with age as a potential confounder.

I have been modelling this using a logistic regression, with logit link using a model like

$$A \sim  \mathrm{logit}\,(\alpha+\beta_0\, \mathrm{class} + \beta_1\,\mathrm{age})$$

and reading off the $\beta_0$ coefficient for the log-odds-ratio between the two classes, and using its $p$-value to test significance between the two classes (the presence/absence of $A$ could be explained by different ages). This is easily tested using `glm` in R.

However, this only works if there is at least one count of $A$ in each class. With a zero count, this doesn't converge (obviously). Removing age as a variable means that there is a 2x2 contingency table (the totals in each class are known), and a Fisher exact test can be applied.

There is an obvious cut-off into two age groups, which means that the model can be effectively reduced into a 2x2x2 contingency table, along these lines:

```
Age-group 1:      A  not-A
       Class 1    0   1250
       Class 2    2    100

Age-group 2:      A  not-A
       Class 1    0    850
       Class 2   10     20
```

(example data)

Aside from running two separate Fisher tests on each, and correcting the p-values that arise from it, is there a test I can run to do both tests simultaneously, and extract the "class" effect?

Comment: I found the [paper](https://doi.org/10.1136/bmj.i1981) by Greenland et al. on this topic illuminating. They also suggest simple methods for dealing with the problem, namely penalised estimation.